# How to get every value from one column to another column based on its corresponding value

Tags: excel, function

[image: Excel Problem]

As you can see in the image that "Col B" has same number multiple times. For ex: "1" is four times, "2" is three times, and so on. However, all these numbers correspond to a specific number from "Col A". What I am trying to do is get the the column I have highlighted in orange and yellow. You can clearly see what I have done. What I need is a excel function that does it for me. This is just a sample. I have dataset with million data points, and I can't type all that.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formula for cell `E2`

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF($B:$B=$D2,ROW($B:$B)-1),COLUMN(A:A)),"")
```

Entered as an Array Formula (Enter with Ctrl-Shift-Enter rather than just Enter)

Copy accross for as many cells as you wish

Note: this formula is quite slow.  A well designed UDF will be faster.

One way to solve this with a UDF is

```
Function MultiLookup(Val As Variant, rItems As Range, rLookup As Range, Index As Long) As Variant
    Dim vItems As Variant
    Dim i As Long, n As Long

    With rItems
        If IsEmpty(.Cells(.Count)) Then
            Set rItems = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Count).End(xlUp))
        End If
    End With

    vItems = rItems
    n = 0
    For i = 1 To UBound(vItems, 1)
        If vItems(i, 1) = Val Then
            n = n + 1
            If n = Index Then
                MultiLookup = rLookup.Cells(i, 1)
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next
    MultiLookup = vbNullString
End Function
```

Use like this, for cell `E2`

```
=MultiLookup($D2,$B:$B,$A:$A,COLUMN(A:A))
```

Again, copy accross for as many cells as use wish

Comment: That does it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another non UDF solution, that works fast. Please note that it uses the `AGGREGATE`-Function, which is only available since Excel-2010.

Put this in E2 and drag across.

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$1000,AGGREGATE(15,6,Row($1:$1000)/($B$2:$B$1000=$D2),COLUMN(A:A)))
```

You can also wrap this formula with a `IFERROR` to make sure you don't get the `#VALUE!` Error.

Answer (score 0):

A PivotTable, with it's body copied into D2 and then blanks removed should be quick:

[image: SO34114099 example]